# Logs sent to console using logback configuration in java app, not visible in Kubernetes using kubectl logs

Tags: kubernetes, logback, kubectl, kubelet

I read in kubernetes docs somewhere that kubernetes reads application logs from stdout and stderror in pods. 
I created a new application and configured it to send logs to a remote splunk hec endpoint (using splunk-logback jars) and at the same time to console. 
So by default, the console logs in logback should go to System.out, which should then be visible using kubectl logs .
But it's not happening in my application.

my logback file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration>

    <Appender name="SPLUNK" class="com.splunk.logging.HttpEventCollectorLogbackAppender">
        <url>${splunk_hec_url}</url>
        <token>${splunk_hec_token}</token>
        <index>${splunk_app_token}</index>
        <disableCertificateValidation>true</disableCertificateValidation>
        <batch_size_bytes>1000000</batch_size_bytes>
        <batch_size_count>${batch_size_count}</batch_size_count>
        <send_mode>sequential</send_mode>

        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <pattern>%msg</pattern>
        </layout>
    </Appender>

    <Appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%msg</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </Appender>

    <Appender name="ASYNC" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </Appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="SPLUNK"/>
        <appender-ref ref="ASYNC"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

I am able to see the logs in splunk and If I login to the container from backend and start my java application, then also I can see the logs on the terminal that time. But if I let the container start by default on it's own, then the logs are only going to splunk and I can't view them using `kubectl logs <POD_NAME>`

The kubernetes yml file for my logger app:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
    name: logging-pod
    labels:
       app: logging-pod
spec:
  containers:
     - name: logging-container
       image: logger-splunk:latest
       command: ["java", "-jar", "logger-splunk-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
       resources:
          requests:
             cpu: 1
             memory: 1Gi
          limits:
             cpu: 1
             memory: 1Gi
```

Comment: _If I login to the container from backend and start my java application_ what does that mean?

Comment: Just for testing, can you remove the AsyncAppender and log directly to STDOUT? Does that make a difference?

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel logging to container, I mean attaching to the pod interactively `kubectl exec -it <pod> -- /bin/sh` and then run the command "java -jar logger-splunk-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" from the shell

Comment: @ewramner First I tried with the STDOUT only, I applied the asyncAppender later on, but both are not working

Comment: Ashu, just want to let you know that there are some other options how you can get the logs from your application in Splunk and keep them on local nodes as well to be able to use `kubectl logs` command. You can try our solution https://www.outcoldsolutions.com/ that forwards Application Logs, metrics, host logs and more to Splunk and provides dashboards for exploring this data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so this finally got resolved. The issue was with the logs not being flushed.

In the PatternLayout the %n was missing. Hence everything was going into some buffer I guess and not reaching the console.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Kubenetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/), all output (that a containerized application writes to `stdout` and `stderr`) is redirected to a JSON file by default. You can access it by using `kubectl logs`.

Let's test this feature by creating a simple pod that outputs numbers in stdout:

```
kubectl create -f https://k8s.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/counter-pod.yaml
```

*counter-pod.yaml:*

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: counter
spec:
  containers:
  - name: count
    image: busybox
    args: [/bin/sh, -c,
            'i=0; while true; do echo "$i: $(date)"; i=$((i+1)); sleep 1; done']
```

where:
 `counter` - name of the pod
 `count`   - name of the container inside "counter" pod

You can access the content of that file by running:

```
$ kubectl logs counter
```

You can access a log file of previously crashed container in a pod by the following command:

```
$ kubectl logs --previous
```

In case of multiple containers in the pod, you should add the name of the container as follows:

```
$ kubectl logs counter -c count
```

When the pod is removed from the cluster, all its logs (current and previous) are also removed.

Ensure you configure stdout in application correctly, and the output to stdout in your application is not silently skipped by any reason.