# Spring boot application logs in Kubernetes

Tags: java, kubernetes

I have a spring boot app with System.out.println statements. Running as a docker, I am able to see the application logs on the console doing `docker -f logs`.

However when I deploy this app in Kubernetes, not able to see the output from System.out.println in pod logs. Even with `kubectl logs -f` does not display the logging output.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: you should get that doing  kubectl logs <pod-name>. What does kubectl logs <podname> give you ? Is your pod in running state ?

Comment: paste the output of pod describe and get pods , and pod logs commands

Comment: Shashank...Yes, the pod is up and running. Spring Boot framework logs show up when I do the kubectl logs <podname>, but not the application level System.our.println statements I have in my code...

Comment: Can you paste the pod definition as well

Comment: Maybe this is similar to your problem? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50263724/logs-sent-to-console-using-logback-configuration-in-java-app-not-visible-in-kub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50263724/logs-sent-to-console-using-logback-configuration-in-java-app-not-visible-in-kub)

Comment: Voted to close since there's no solution and no follow-up to clarify the question with definitions/etc.

Comment: Do you still have this problem ?
Could you please provide Pod manifest file ?

Comment: @Satya I'm experiencing the exact same issue, did you find a solution?